# Can you save strings from loops then later combine them with other strings?

Tags: python

So I'm (very badly) coding a hangman game in python and I've run into a bit of an issue that some google searches wouldn't seem to fix for me. So I have a string (word) and every time the user guesses a letter in this word correctly it displays the string (known_word) that displays a list of empty spaces with some being replaced by the letters they guessed in their respective places. Here is an example:

```
word = 'coffee'
answer = 'e'
known_word = '****ee'
```

After the word is displayed they are looped back to input another guess. However, when they loop back and guess another letter (correct or not) it does not display the letters that have already been guessed. Because of this, I am wondering if there is any easy way to save the value of known_word and add the new guesses to known_word so that all letters guessed so far word be displayed.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to store the answers in a list. Then you can compare each character in `word` with the values in the `answer` list to generate the `known_word` string. For example:

```py
word = 'coffee'
answer = ['e', 'o']
known_word = ''.join(c if c in answer else '*' for c in word)
```

Output:

```
*o**ee
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating the known_word iteratively as you receive each answer, you could use a function like this to update

```
def update_known_word(word, answer, known_word):    
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if(word[i] == answer):
            known_word = known_word[:i] + word[i] + known_word[i+1:]

    return known_word
```

The flow would look something like this. Typed it out step by step just for demonstration purposes but you would use a loop instead.

```
word = 'coffee'
known_word = '******'

# Get answer from user
answer = 'e'

known_word = update_known_word(word, answer, known_word)
print(known_word)

# Get answer from user
answer = 'c'

known_word = update_known_word(word, answer, known_word)
print(known_word)
```

Output:

```
****ee
c***ee
```

With a loop:

```
while(word_not_found):
   # Get answer from user for this iteration
   known_word = update_known_word(word, answer, known_word)
   print(known_word)
```